# delete variable by reference

Tags: php, reference, php-5.3

given the following code:

```
$tree = array();
$node =& $tree[];
// imagine tons of code that populates $tree here
```

how can i entirely delete the ZVAL `$node` points to *by reference*? Is that even possible?

Using `unset()`, only the reference is destroyed and not the node in `$tree` itself:

```
unset($node);
print_r($tree);

// outputs:
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
```

I know this is the expected behaviour of `unset($reference)` and I also know how the ZVAL refcounter works.

But i really need to delete that node after processing in a specific corner case.

Can i somehow find the correct array index and unset the array element directly like `unset($tree[$node_index])`?

**Disclaimer**: The above example is minified and isolated. Actually i'm modifying a complex parser for a really ugly nested table data structure that is presented as a stream. The code heavily uses pointers as backreferences and i'd like to avoid refactoring the whole code.

Comment: "Can i somehow find the correct array index" - the easiest way is to save it somewhere, when creating a new array element here: $tree[]

Comment: @Kaii guess your question was incomplete before the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you grab a reference to an array element and unset the reference the array will not be affected at all -- that's just how `unset` works, and this behavior is not negotiable.

What you need to do is remember the key of the element in question and `unset` directly on the array afterwards:

```
$tree = array();
$tree[] = 'whatever';

end($tree);
$key = key($tree);

// ...later on...

unset($tree[$key]);
```

Of course this is extremely ugly and it requires you to keep both `$tree` (or a *reference* to it) and `$key` around. You can mitigate this somewhat by packaging the unset operation into an anonymous function -- if there's a good chance you *are* going to pull the trigger later, the convenience could offset the additional resource consumption:

```
$tree = array();
$tree[] = 'whatever';

end($tree);
$key = key($tree);

$killThisItem = function() use(&$tree, $key) { unset($tree[$key]); } ;

// ...later on...

$killThisItem();
```

Comment: Didn't find better than the end/key combination either.

Comment: @Kethryweryn: There is none. You can write an expression with no side effects that produces the same result, but it will be horribly wasteful unless the array is tiny.